# How to read a file line by line and then output all lines compounded with sth in jq?

Tags: json, constructor, jq

If we need to read dynamic parameters from a static file and then generate one target (url) for each line of the file, how to use jq to implement it?
I mean, we use jq to read a file and then process its contents line by line; the output for each line is a distinct url generated with a line respectively.

Could anyone please provide one or several examples? Thank you very much!

For example, there is a file called tels.txt which contains numerous phone no:
13512345678
13712345600
17212215600
13512345889
18912345678
13912345678
18612345999

jq --slurpfile phoneNos tels.txt '.phoneNo=$phoneNos'  | jq -cM '{method: "POST", url: "http://:6060", body: {phoneNo: .} | @json}'

I want to generate output like {method: "POST", url: "http://:6060", body: {phoneNo: 13512345678}} for each line in the above file, but when executing the the jq commandline as the above, got nothing.

My question is how the commandline should be, thx

Comment: Hi, this isn't a coding service. We are here to help with specific problems. Please read up on how to ask questions here, and provide us details of what you have tried, and why it's not working.

Comment: For example, there is a file called tels.txt which contains numerous phone no:
13512345678
13712345600
17212215600
13512345889
18912345678
13912345678
18612345999

jq --slurpfile phoneNos tels.txt '.phoneNo=$phoneNos'  | jq -cM '{method: "POST", url: "http://:6060", body: {phoneNo: .} | @json}'

I want to generate output like {method: "POST", url: "http://:6060", body: {phoneNo: 13512345678}} for each line in the above file, but when executing the the jq commandline as the above, got nothing.

My question is how the commandline should be, thx

Comment: The illustrated output should be valid JSON, shouldn't it?  For guidelines about asking questions on SO, please see [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming tels.txt has the telephone numbers exactly as you want them, one per line, you could write:

```
jq -R '{method: "POST", url: "http://:6060", body: {phoneNo: .}}' tels.txt
```

Notice there is no need to invoke jq twice. Indeed, invoking jq twice in a row (`jq ... | jq ...`) is usually suboptimal.

Comment: @fengnix please mark this as the answer so that others can reference it, and so the answering person gets the credit.

Comment: @jdpjamesp How to specify it as the answer?